# Конфигурационные файлы сервера Apache

Tags: apache

Вопрос по учебному заданию. 
Нужно привести примеры фрагментов конфигурационных файлов сервера Apache для доменов test.ru, test2.ru, www.test2.ru.
Домены test.ru и test2.ru ссылаются на разные (любые) папки, домен www.test2.ru и test2.ru на одну папку.   
Для всех доменов должен быть включен модуль mod_headers, а для доменов test2.ru и www.test2.ru добавить для html файлов фильтр mod_deflate.

Подскажите, правильно ли мое решение и укажите на ошибки, если они есть.

```
ServerName test.ru
DocumentRoot “/home/www/test/”
# Подключение модуля mod_headers
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

ServerName test2.ru
DocumentRoot “/home/www/test2/”
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.test2.ru
    DocumentRoot “/home/www/test2/”
</VirtualHost>
# Подключение модуля mod_headers
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
# Подключение модуля mod_headers
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
```

Answer (score 1):

Это делается примерно так:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/test1/www"
    ServerName test.ru
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/test2/www"
    ServerName test2.ru
    ServerAlias www.test2.ru
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: не,у меня у первого домена,test.ru,алиасов же нет

    # test
    ServerName test.ru
    DocumentRoot “/home/www/test/”
    # Подключение модуля mod_headers
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    
    
    # test2
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/test2/www"
        ServerName test2.ru
        ServerAlias www.test2.ru
    </VirtualHost>
    # Подключение модуля mod_headers
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    # Подключение модуля deflate_module
    LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/htm

Comment: вот так будет правильно?

Comment: Отсутствие алиаса у первого хоста не лишает его статуса хоста, то есть для него тоже нужен VirtualHost. Просто убери "ServerAlias www.test1.ru".
И вынеси LoadModule в какое-то одно место (например, в начале), для удобного поиска в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0):

Для удобства разделим на задания 
1) Домены test.ru и test2.ru ссылаются на разные (любые) папки,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/html/test1/www/"
    ServerName test1.ru
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/html/test2/www/"
    ServerName test2.ru
</VirtualHost>
```

2) Домен www.test2.ru и test2.ru на одну папку.
Вариант 1.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/html/test1/www/"
ServerName test1.ru
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/html/test1/www/"
ServerName test2.ru
</VirtualHost>
```

Вариант 2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/html/test1/www/"
ServerName test1.ru
ServerAlias test2.ru
</VirtualHost>
```

Модули подключаются в секции Dynamic Shared Support

По умолчанию они включены

```
#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#

LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```